# user assignment in Sessions_Helper Rails 3 Tutorial Ch.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Hartl's tutorial book using Rails 3.1.1 with everything working fine until reaching Chapter 9 and updating _header.html.erb with layout links.  Once I make the changes to the _header.html.erb and the spec/.../layout_links rspec returns failures and the local webserver returns error messages instead of the webpage.  The problem appears to be the 'user' in the sessions_helper.rb.  I typed in following code as in Listing 9.26 of the book:

```
<header>
    <%= link_to logo, root_path %>

    <nav class="round">
      <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %></li>
            <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
            <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

After doing this, getting error message when trying to display on local server:

```
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x4f4b1d0>:0x4f3a370>
```

which traces back to the <% if signed_in? %>

My sessions_helper file is:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    current_user = nil
  end

  private

  def user_from_remember_token
    user.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
  end

  def remember_token
    cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
  end
end
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your

```
def user_from_remember_token
    user.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end
```

should be: (user should be capitalized)

```
def user_from_remember_token
    User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end
```

I'm assuming you have the authentication code in your User class. In the user_from_remember_token, you're going to be referring to the class methods, as you have no User instantiation at that point.

Comment: Thank you much.  That worked and I'm completely embarrassed that I missed something so simple and didn't catch it as I was tracing the problem.

Comment: It happens to everyone - especially in a language like Ruby that isn't strongly typed